# Pass different commandparameters to same command using RelayCommand WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, commandparameter

So, what I am trying to achieve here is to use the same command to execute some different kind of code. The way I want to distinguish between the code I want to be executed can be done using commandparameters. I just don't see how I can do it the way I want to, when I have to use the RelayCommand.

This means, that I have 2 different buttons, that both uses the same command, just with different commandparameters.

This is my XAML so far:

```
<RibbonButton SmallImageSource="../Images/whatever.png" Label="Attribute" Command="{Binding AddItemToNodeCommand}" CommandParameter="Attribute"/>

<RibbonButton SmallImageSource="../Images/whatever.png" Label="Method" Command="{Binding AddItemToNodeCommand}" CommandParameter="Method" />
```

This is what I have in my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand AddItemToNodeCommand { get; private set; }
```

and of course:

```
AddItemToNodeCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItemToNode);
```

Is there some way that I can be able to use that commandparameter when calling the relayCommand?

If you need any more information, or code please just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression to give you access to the `CommandParameter`... try this:

```
AddItemToNodeCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter => AddItemToNode(parameter));
```

Please note that (as with all lambda expressions) the name `parameter` here *could* be anything... this would work just the same:

```
AddItemToNodeCommand = new RelayCommand(p => AddItemToNode(p));
```

This is because we are simply setting the input parameter name for it before the `=>`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Have you tried it like this?:

```
AddItemToNodeCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(parameter => AddItemToNode(parameter));
```

The last option is just to call it in the same way as you started with:

```
AddItemToNodeCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItemToNode);
```

Comment: That last bit did the trick, thank you! I don't really understand why, since a lot of other examples on the web seems to be using it without the <object>. But again thank you!